# How do I get all the keywords and check which ones I have already selected?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm developing a keyword system (tagging, topics) on my website and I have the following problem:

1 - There are a lot of topics on my website:
economy, hobbies, lifestyle, religion, art, politics etc...

2 - So I choose 2:HOBBIES and LIFESTYLE.

Problem:

3 - After... when I go to edit my profile, I'll need to select all topics and check among results, which ones I have already selected:

economy, **HOBBIES**, **LIFESTYLE**, religion, art, politics.

How do I do that using mysql queries? I need to use subqueries?

**UPDATE**

Tables:

**PROFILE**:(profile_id)

**PROFILE_TOPICS**:(profile_id,topic_id)

**TOPICS**:(topic_id,topic_name)

Comment: Your table `PROFILE_TOPICS` has a list of all topics that have been used. You just need to get a unique list of the `topic_id` values.

Comment: The PROFILE table is where I save the users profile.

Comment: The TOPICS table is where I have saved all topics available on my website

Comment: The PROFILE_TOPICS is where I connect the tables: PROFILE and TOPICS

Comment: Yes, and if you get all the topic ids in the PROFILE_TOPICS table, that is a list of all the topics that have been used.

Comment: With left join, it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id,t.topic_name,ct.topic_id FROM topics AS t LEFT JOIN profile_topics AS ct ON t.id=ct.topic_id AND ct.profile_id=? ORDER BY t.topic_name ASC;

$id=$row->id;
$topic_id=$row->topic_id;
$topic_name=$row->topic_name;

if($id==$topic_id){}else{}
```